# Fastest way to load a dynamic select with php

Tags: php, select, load

I'm developing a client management system for my workplace using PHP and MySQL. Every page loads a header.php file which contains, among other things, the navigation menu and a dropdown box which dynamically loads all of the client names so that I can quickly jump to their contact card. Long names are shortened, with the full name as the 'title'.

However, every page has to pause at this point while it loads the list before it can continue loading the rest of the page.

Here's my code:

```
<select>
<?
$select = "SELECT id, name FROM customers ORDER BY name ASC";
$query  = @mysql_query($select,$con) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $cust_id   = $data['id'];
    $cust_name = substr($data['name'], 0, 14);
    $cust_name_long = "";
    if (strlen($data['name']) >= 15){
       $cust_name .= "...";
       $cust_name_long = $data['name'];
    }
    echo '<option title="'.$cust_name_long.'" value="customers-edit.php?id='.$cust_id.'">'.$cust_name.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

What's a more efficient way of doing this, so that I don't have the 2-second pause every time a page opens? I could settle with loading the dropdown list after the rest of the page has loaded, or loading a cached version of the dropdown list unless customer names have changed, or......?

Comment: How long is that list?! A simple query and output like that shouldn't take 2 seconds.

Comment: yes. it should not take that much time. check if you have index in the table customers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suspect that you have a really large list of customers, if that is the case then dont use drop down, use autosuggest. otherwise check if your customers table has indexes

Comment: no idea but I upvoted again :-) by the way, I too suspect that an index on the column `names` would solve this problem on the MySQL side. another approach would indeed be autocompletion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
or you could consider "lazily" loading that list in the background, by setting an onclick event on the dropdown and doing an AJAX call (using something like jQuery) to a PHP script to fetch the requested data and then put them into the dropdown using JS; but if there's many customers, your users will probably prefer autocomplete anyway.

Comment: Thanks all. The customers table has 1835 rows and already had an index on the names column. Autosuggest makes much more sense and I'll definitely be doing that, don't know why I went with a dropdown...